# ViewModel not updated when inside TextBox LostFocus event

Tags: wpf, events, wpf-controls, viewmodel

I have a LostFocus event attached to my TextBox. This TextBox is bound to a ViewModel. However when I lose focus on the TextBox and enter the LostFocus event I find that that the property on the ViewModel has not been updated. It is still showing the old value that I had in the TextBox.

What event should I be using to ensure the ViewModel is updated before I execute any code in my event?

I realise that this might not be normal design, but just to give you some background. I have a  grid with dynamic columns that are based on the contexts on the TextBox. I updated these when the TextBox loses focus. I also have a validation rule against the TextBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your Binding something like

```
Text="{Binding Path=Val}"
```

make sure yout also have

```
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

Comment: That seems to do it, but I don't need TwoWay binding. Can you explain why you have specified it?

Comment: the job should be done with just UpdateSourceTrigger. Just a habbit of mine. remove it if you don't want it. Just thought you needed it.